# Can box-shadow CSS property be animated? Chrome animates, Firefox does not

Tags: css, css-animations

Below is the jsfiddle.net example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PGa2H/

CSS

```
@keyframes blink {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 15px green; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 0; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 15px green; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 15px green; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 0; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 15px green; }
}

.blink {
    -webkit-animation: blink 1.0s linear infinite;
    animation: blink 1.0s linear infinite;
}
```

- Box shadow animation works in Chrome
- Does not work in Firefox

Questions

- Which CSS3 properties can be animated?
- Where this is specified?
- If there is an issue with Firefox, is there a reference for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox doesn't seem to like it if you use an invalid `box-shadow` value for some reason.  If you want to cancel the shadow use `box-shadow: none`.  This seems to be all it takes to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/PGa2H/2/

This seems to be an unofficial but accurate list of animatable properties: http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/

Comment: Perfect! Confused box-shadow with border (border: 0 seems legit).